# Minecraft 1.16.4 Spigot new netherite items issue

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

Trying to implement the plugin that will make players drop only expensive items. Here is shortcut of the code:

```
    public HashMap<Player , ItemStack[]> items = new HashMap<Player , ItemStack[]>();

    @EventHandler
    public void onDeath(PlayerDeathEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getEntity().getGameMode().equals(GameMode.SURVIVAL))
        {
            ItemStack[] content = event.getEntity().getInventory().getContents();
            items.put(event.getEntity(), content);
            event.getDrops().removeIf(stack -> !this.isExpensive(stack.getType().toString()));
            // isExpensive method returns 1 if the itemstack is expensive, 0 either
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onRespawn(PlayerRespawnEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getPlayer().getGameMode().equals(GameMode.SURVIVAL) && items.containsKey(event.getPlayer()))
        {
            for (ItemStack stack : items.get(event.getPlayer()))
            {
                if (!this.isExpensive(stack.getType().toString()))
                    event.getPlayer().getInventory().addItem(stack);
            }
            items.remove(event.getPlayer());
        }
    }
```

It works fine, but there is a problem with new netherite blocks, their .typeName().toString() is "AIR", I wrote the following code in PlayerDeathEvent method to check this:

```
for (ItemStack stack : event.getDrops())
    plugin.getLogger().info(stack.getType().toString());
```

and here is the result:

```
[01:34:40 INFO]: h4sv issued server command: /give h4sv minecraft:diamond
[01:34:40 INFO]: §7§o[h4sv: Gave 1 [Diamond] to h4sv]
[01:34:44 INFO]: h4sv issued server command: /give h4sv minecraft:netherite_ingot
[01:34:44 INFO]: §7§o[h4sv: Gave 1 [Netherite Ingot] to h4sv]
[01:34:47 INFO]: h4sv issued server command: /give h4sv minecraft:netherite_block
[01:34:47 INFO]: §7§o[h4sv: Gave 1 [Block of Netherite] to h4sv]
[01:35:00 INFO]: h4sv issued server command: /give h4sv netherite_scrap
[01:35:00 INFO]: §7§o[h4sv: Gave 1 [Netherite Scrap] to h4sv]
[01:35:05 INFO]: h4sv issued server command: /give h4sv minecraft:ancient_debris
[01:35:05 INFO]: §7§o[h4sv: Gave 1 [Ancient Debris] to h4sv]
[01:35:10 INFO]: h4sv issued server command: /give h4sv minecraft:acacia_sapling 64
[01:35:10 INFO]: §7§o[h4sv: Gave 64 [Acacia Sapling] to h4sv]
[01:35:16 INFO]: h4sv issued server command: /kill
[01:35:16 INFO]: DIAMOND
[01:35:16 INFO]: AIR
[01:35:16 INFO]: AIR
[01:35:16 INFO]: AIR
[01:35:16 INFO]: AIR
[01:35:16 INFO]: SAPLING
[01:35:16 INFO]: h4sv fell out of the world
```

I'm running server on Paper 1.16.4 build 337, and using Spigot 1.16.4 (latest build) as plugin library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because at the moment when the player dies (the `PlayerDeathEvent` gets triggered) his inventory already dropped the item, so the slot becomes empty this explains the `AIR` value, but that's strange this is happening only with netherite items.
However you could get around this issue by using the `org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDeathEvent#getDrops` method, which returns all items, including netherite stuff.